# randint is not available on an example group

Tags: ruby, pruebas-unitarias, rspec

Tengo la siguiente prueba unitaria:

```
describe "Basic tests" do
  Test.assert_equals(decompose_single_strand("AGGTGACACCGCAAGCCTTATATTAGC"), "Frame 1: AGG TGA CAC CGC AAG CCT TAT ATT AGC\nFrame 2: A GGT GAC ACC GCA AGC CTT ATA TTA GC\nFrame 3: AG GTG ACA CCG CAA GCC TTA TAT TAG C")
end

describe "Random tests" do
def randint(a,b) rand(b-a+1)+a end
def sol(s) (0..2).map{|i| "Frame #{i+1}: #{((i==0 ? [] : [s.slice(0,i)])+s.slice(i,s.size).scan(/.{1,3}/)).join(" ")}"}.join("\n") end
base="ACGT"

40.times do
  s=(0...randint(1,20)*3).map{base[randint(0,3)]}.join
  it "Testing for #{s.inspect}" do
  Test.assert_equals(decompose_single_strand(s),sol(s),"It should work for random inputs too")
  end
end
end
```

Al cambiar la prueba unitaria de MRI 2.5.0 a MRI 3.0.0 me arroja el error

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/solution_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: s=(0...randint(1,20)*3).map{base[randint(0,3)]}.join
  `randint` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc).
# ./spec/solution_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/solution_spec.rb:10:in `times'
# ./spec/solution_spec.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/solution_spec.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para corregirla y que de preferencia sea retrocompatible?

Comment: Una sugerencia loca, pero ¿y que tal borrar todo el bloque de random tests?. Se me hace que cualquier cambio en `decompose_single_strand` implicaría cambiar además el método `sol(s)`. Por lo que tengo entendido, no es muy recomendable meter lógica con ese nivel de acoplamiento dentro de un test. Aparte me queda la duda sobre la efectividad de realizar 40 tests para valores al azar, creo que sería más valioso testear los valores específicos que puedan alcanzar ciertas condiciones dentro de la lógica de `decompose_single_strand` en vez de dar valores al azar para ver si algún día el test falla.

Comment: si borro las prueba aleatorias se alocan en codewars, es lo único que medianamente garantiza que las soluciones no sean hackeadas